# Recursion method for arraylist

Tags: c#, recursion, methods

I got a little bit stuck in a recursive sum calculation.

I have a container class of Students and all students are in object class Student(student has their name, last name... and their grades). I am saving student's grades in arraylist and I want a recursive method in container class which could calculate those grades inside the ArrayList. I know how to do it in iterative way, but not sure about recursive version of it.

**Student class**

```
class Student
{
    public ArrayList grades = new ArrayList();

    public Student(ArrayList grades)
    {
        this.grades = grades;
    }
}
```

**Students class(Container)**

```
class Students
{
    private Student[] studentOb{ get; set; }
    public int containerNumber{ get; private set; }
    
    public Students(int size)
    {
        studentOb = new Student[size];
    }

    public void AddElement(Student info)
    {
        studentOb[containerNumber++] = info;
    }

    public Student TakeElement(int index)
    {
        return studentOb[index];
    }

    //this is where I am trying to build that Sum method, and yeah my code is just nonsense
    public int Sum(ArrayList collection)
    {
        int ret = collection.Count;

        foreach (ArrayList newList in collection)
        {
            ret += Sum(newList)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use `ArrayList`, if you can use `List<int>` and `Linq` extension?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Calculating a sum of a simple list of values recursively is pointless for real-world code, so clearly your teacher has some particular academic goal in mind here. But there are many different ways to approach a recursive solution. The simplest would just use recursion to enumerate index values, but other solutions might actually specify a new subset of the list, or even create a whole new list. This question would really be much better answered by your teacher, but if you must have help here, you need to be more clear about what your assignment is.

Comment: What exactly is your collection representing? I mean, it doesn't even access properties of the class, does it? Then you could even make it static. But if the arraylist just represents the students in a list, it's not a good idea to make it recursively in c#. If you'd use a functional language such as Haskell, ok, but for that task you need methods like head and tail, which you had to write your own in c# and in the end it would only be slow... I think you got the mistake in thinking that this is just like a file system, but in your case you only had a few directories with a few files in it.

Comment: @MetaColon it does access , i just shorten my code here, I got more properties than this list. Guys and the main goal is simple , atleast that's what I think , I am just not sure how to write it correctly. I need a recursive method  inside container to sum Student[i] grades and then compare that sum with other students.

Comment: You can sum using `int Sum(ArrayList list, int index = 0) { return index < ArrayList.Count ? (int)list[index] + Sum(list, index + 1) : 0; }`. Comparing to other students is a different question. But is this what your teacher wants? No one here can know. You need to ask your teacher. And if you don't ask your teacher, getting an answer here doesn't help you, because you lost the opportunity to have it _explained_ to you in a way that leaves you with more knowledge than you started with.

Comment: @PeterDuniho thanks , mate , yup , I will discuss this task with my teacher :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that without recursion (which is not the best solution here). Using LINQ and SelectMany you can write the Sum method as:

```
public int Sum()
{
    return studentOb.SelectMany(x => x.grades.Cast<int>()).Sum();
}
```

You can also improve the code and replace ArrayLists with typed collections.

Comment: I know it is not the best , but this is what my task ask's me to do ...